# How do I get gitscc to use hooks?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

I'm using [gitscc](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/releases/view/46589) with Visual Studio 2010, and would like to run some hooks. If I run git from the command line or with git extensions it will run my hooks just fine (specifically a post-commit hook), but if I commit using the gitscc window it does not execute my hook. My Google searches have been fruitless.

My directory structure looks like this (other files omitted):

```
Solution Dir/
    Project Dir/
        .git/
            hooks/
               post-commit
```

The contents of my `post-commit` file are:

```
#!/bin/sh
C:/Python32/python.exe "C:/scripts/test.py"
```

and `test.py` contains:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
with open('run.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('I ran!')
```

My gitscc.config file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GitSccOptions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <GitBashPath>C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe</GitBashPath>
  <GitExtensionPath>C:\Program Files\GitExtensions\GitExtensions.exe</GitExtensionPath>
  <DifftoolPath>c:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe</DifftoolPath>
  <TortoiseGitPath>C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseProc.exe</TortoiseGitPath>
  <NotExpandTortoiseGit>false</NotExpandTortoiseGit>
  <NotExpandGitExtensions>false</NotExpandGitExtensions>
  <UseTGitIconSet>false</UseTGitIconSet>
</GitSccOptions>
```

When I commit from the command line, it generates `ran.txt` in my Project Dir, and a Tkinter window pops up. When I run from the 'Git Pending Changes' window in Visual Studio, I get bupkis.

Is there some setting I need to change, am I missing something, does gitscc just not run hooks, or is there something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the previous version of gitscc didn't fire off the hooks. I posted a [bug report](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/workitem/16690).

The newest version should fire the hooks.